# Failed to initialize central HHBC repository: Failed to initialize schema

Tags: composer-php, hhvm

The complete error is:

```
Failed to initialize central HHBC repository:
Failed to initialize schema in /home/shreeram/.hhvm.hhbc:
```

I am trying to configure hhvm ana apache2.
 For that i am following this link    [how-to-setup-hhvm-on-ubuntu-14-04-server-with-apache-2-4-part-1/](https://runtimereflection.wordpress.com/2015/06/29/how-to-setup-hhvm-on-ubuntu-14-04-server-with-apache-2-4-part-1/)

In above link i am stuck in the step when i put this command in the terminal:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

The result of that command is the error mentioned above.

The shreeram directory has both read and write permission.

Could anyone help me to understand what i am missing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you *sure* permissions are correct on `/home/shreeram`, and that `/home/shreeram/.hhvm.hhbc` is readable and writable by the user running `php`? This issue really does sound like a permissions problem.

As the same user that was running `php`, does `touch /home/shreeram/.hhvm.hhbc` work? What about `echo > /home/shreeram/.hhvm.hhbc`?

If that's all fine, try `rm /home/shreeram/.hhvm.hhbc` and then try to install Composer again. Although it's typically a permission error, there are cases when the repo can become corrupt (particularly if the enclosing directory is on NFS or some other network filesystem) and you can just remove it and start over.